# How to use a different value each time postman runs a test through newman

Tags: teamcity, postman, newman

I have some tests in Postman that we are trying to automate. Currently whenever the QA people go in to test they manually change the body of the request to use a different ID number each time.

What we want is for some kind of ability for that number to be changed each time using either a data sheet or some other way to increment the number. I have found the documentation for using a data sheet, the issue is this is more for if you want to use different values during iterations of a test. The next time you run the test though, it will go back to the first value and begin again. What I would need is a large list of values and for Postman to only pick the next value in the list each time the test was run.

Example list:

1234
1235
1236
1237

Today I run the test and it picks 1234. In 2 weeks when I run it again, it picks 1235. Three days after that I run the test again and it picks 1236.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi, You could set an environment or global variable with your last used id + 1, then get it at the beginning of your request (in pre-request script). With newman you can use those in the command line (-e <env_var>.json for environment variables)

Comment: have a look at the options here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options

Answer (score 4):

Im facing this Problem right now. I tried this solution so far and it worked.
I wrote an initiating Script, that sets the Environment Variables to a default state, but you can write it yourself in the Environment. Just put a Value Name (e.g "ID") with a specific value (e.g. your 1234)

In my case I have a If condition. For you should following work:

Set

```
var id = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("ID");
```

on top of your Test Script. Then before your script is going to exit, just write the following line

```
id++;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ID", id);
```

this sets the counter from the ID +1 to 1235 and stores it in the environment variable

I hope this solution works for you. You can replace the Variable names with your needed names of course.

This solution doesn't reset with a new start. It takes the last number with it and continues from there in the next run.